# create mx record in route 53 in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, smtp

i have a domain working fine in elastistic benstalk and i want create a user mail now, and use workmail is expensive to me. I try create a user mail named sistema@playcursos.com. I using mx record in route 53. i config this value

> 10 sistema.playcursos.com

but i try a lot of times and not work

[image]

i use this tutorial for connect in thunderbir but i give a error.
the thunderbird not found my acount config

[image]

and i config my credentials

[image]

Comment: i update my question, but i cant connect using a email service how thunderbird

Comment: Please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the services. [SES (Amazon Simple Email Service)](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) can help you to send email, but not for receiving (no IMAP).

On another side ([Workmail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/)) does offer IMAP but if I am right you don't want to use it.

Now [route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53) is a service for managing DNS, here you add your records like `MX`, but just by adding records it won't make services start to work in your client (SMTP/IMAP)

You could configure your client to only use SES `SMTP` for sending emails not for receiving, for receiving, if required,  you will need another service.

Comment: now i understand. i want only send emails by code, i think use one email service how thunderbird for test. i try send email for my machine but i give error credencials, i will upload application to aws too see if i give sucess thank you very much